# regex expression last match C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like this:

```
   test- qweqw (Barcelona - Bayer) - testestsetset
```

And i need to capture Bayer word.I tried this regex expression ( between "-" and ")" )

```
(?<=-)(.*)(?=\))
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/wI9zD0/2
As you see it worked a bit incorrect.What should i fix?

Comment: You could change the `.` to `[^-]`.

Comment: thanks for working solution,but solution in answer much more faster (13 steps instead of 125)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different regex to do what you are looking for:

```regex
-\s([^()]+)\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wI9zD0/3

Comment: If you want to handle an arbitrary amount of whitespace between the `-` and your identifier (in your example, `Bayer`) you'd like to match, use `\s*` instead of `\s`.  Likewise, if you want to handle whitespace after `Bayer` then you need to add `\s*` after your capture group.  Edited regex: `-\s*([^()\s]+)\s*\)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that, you can use LINQ:

```
string input = "test - qweqw(Barcelona - Bayer) - testestsetset";

string res = String.Join("", input.SkipWhile(c => c != '(')
                                  .SkipWhile(c => c != '-').Skip(1)
                                  .TakeWhile(c => c != ')'))
                   .Trim();

Console.WriteLine(res);  // Bayer
```

Comment: we need regexes because of the current functionality=(